# avoiding garbage data while reading data using a byte buffer

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, byte, buffer

I am trying to write a program to transfer a file between client and server using java tcp sockets I am using buffer size of 64K but The problem I am facing is that when when the tcp sometimes fail to send the whole 64K it sends the remaing part for example 32K in anther go
There for A garbage data of some Spaces or so is being taken by the buffer at reading side to make 64K complete and thus unnecessary data is making the file useless at receiving side.
Is there any solution to overcome this problem ???

I am using TCP protocol this code is using to send data to client

#### Server-side code

```java
File transferFile = new File ("Document.txt"); 
byte [] bytearray = new byte [1024]; 
int byRead=0; 
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile); 
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream(); 
while(byRead>-1) {
  byRead=bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);                
  os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);  
  os.flush();
}
```

#### Client-side code

```java
byte [] bytearray = new byte [1024]; 
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream(); 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\NetBeansProjects\\"+filename);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
currentTot = bytesRead; System.out.println("Data is being read ...");
do {
  bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, 0, (bytearray.length)); 
  if(bytesRead == 0) continue;
  if(bytesRead >= 0) currentTot += bytesRead;
  bos.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
} while(bytesRead > -1);
```

here I tried to skip the loop if the byte is empty by continue; statement but it is not
working.

Comment: yes, the solution is to correctly read and write streams.  most likely you are not using the java `read()` and `write()` methods correctly.

Comment: Is this TCP, or is it UDP? Any chance you might post some of the code?

Comment: I have added the codes please notify me where I am doing wrong

Comment: You have to write bytesRead number of bytes, not bytearray.length number of byte.  The region after bytesRead in bytearray is random garbage.

Answer (score 0):

```
bos.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
```

This should be

```
bos.write(bytearray,0,bytesRead);
```

The region after 'bytesRead' in the buffer is undisturbed by the read. It isn't 'garbage'. It's just whatever was there before.

Answer (score 0):

use CLIENT Side Code as below to get the total write bytes without garbage

```java
int availableByte = socket.available();
if (availableByte > 0) {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[availableByte];
  int bytesRead = socketInputStream.read(buffer);
  FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(FilePath, true);
  OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
  BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
  bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString());
  bufferedWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.